# Creating security domain using wildfly-maven-plugin has no effect

Tags: maven, jboss, pom.xml, wildfly, wildfly-8

I found [this](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/execute-commands-example.html) which uses `/subsystem` in its command, so I tried it with a different subsystem command (I use one to create a security domain), it builds successfully, but has no effect in standalone.xml.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
            <configuration>
                <execute-commands>
                    <commands>
                        <command>/subsystem=security/security-domain=secureD:add(cache-type=default)</command>
                        <command>reload</command>
                        <command>/subsystem=security/security-domain=secureD/authentication=classic:add(login-modules=[{"code"=>"Database","flag"=>"required","module-options"=>[("dsJndiName"=>"java:jboss/datasources/MyDB"),("principalsQuery"=>"select password from Users where username=?"),("rolesQuery"=>"select role, 'Roles' from Users where username=?"),("hashAlgorithm"=>"SHA-256"),("hashEncoding"=>"hex"),("hashCharset"=>"UTF-8")]}])</command>
                        <command>reload</command>
                    </commands>
                </execute-commands>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I execute the commands manually in `$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect` it works and the domain is created.

I use eclipse with the following *Run Configurations*: "Goals: clean package wildfly:deploy" "Profiles: local"

```
<project ...
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                tried pasting code from above once here
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                ...
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            and once here 
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

When building I get these errors:

```
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.1.Final:undeploy (undeploy) @ Project ---
Jul 03, 2015 3:50:36 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
Jul 03, 2015 3:50:36 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
Jul 03, 2015 3:50:36 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
WARN: can't find jboss-cli.xml. Using default configuration values.
Jul 03, 2015 3:50:36 PM org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl printLine
INFO: {"outcome" => "success"}
{"outcome" => "success"}
Jul 03, 2015 3:50:36 PM org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl printLine
INFO: {
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.316 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-03T15:50:36+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/165M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.1.Final:undeploy (undeploy) on project Project: Could not execute goal undeploy on /home/username/workspace/Project/target/Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war. Reason: Command execution failed for command 'reload'. Unsupported ModelControllerClient implementation org.wildfly.plugin.cli.Commands$NonClosingModelControllerClient -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

If I remove the `reload` command I get:

```
...
WARN: can't find jboss-cli.xml. Using default configuration values.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.825 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-03T15:45:23+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/214M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.1.Final:deploy-artifact (deploy_jdbc_driver) on project Project: Could not execute goal deploy-artifact on /home/username/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.35/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar. Reason: Command execution failed for command '/subsystem=security/security-domain=secureD:add(cache-type=default)'. {
[ERROR] "outcome" => "failed",
[ERROR] "failure-description" => "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [
[ERROR] (\"subsystem\" => \"security\"),
[ERROR] (\"security-domain\" => \"secureD\")
[ERROR] ]",
[ERROR] "rolled-back" => true,
[ERROR] "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Are you using `mvn wildfly:execute-commands`?

Comment: I'm using eclipse with the following Run Configurations: "Goals: clean package wildfly:deploy" "Profiles: local". Edited my first post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either add the `wildfly:execute-commands` goal or change your configuration to use the `<before-deployment/>`. The latter is probably a better solution as you'd have to use executions to ensure the commands are executed before your deployment. I'd also only use a `reload` at the end.

```xml
<configuration>
    <before-deployment>
        <commands>
            <command>/subsystem=security/security-domain=secureD:add(cache-type=default)</command>
            <command>/subsystem=security/security-domain=secureD/authentication=classic:add(login-modules=[{"code"=>"Database","flag"=>"required","module-options"=>[("dsJndiName"=>"java:jboss/datasources/MyDB"),("principalsQuery"=>"select password from Users where username=?"),("rolesQuery"=>"select role, 'Roles' from Users where username=?"),("hashAlgorithm"=>"SHA-256"),("hashEncoding"=>"hex"),("hashCharset"=>"UTF-8")]}])</command>
            <command>reload</command>
        </commands>
    </before-deployment>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It works so far that when I try building using Maven a domain is created but I get these errors in the build process: see edited first post.

Comment: The error is telling you that you've already added a security domain called `secureD`. This is like a command you'll want to only run once or place in a try/catch/finally block or if/else block. See https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-18731 and https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/If-elseControlFlow